# Pegar dados do MySQL com PHP e passar pra JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estou tentando usar jquery para fazer um auto complete no meu campo de pesquisa. 
A conexão com o banco está correta e utilizo o seguinte código para salvar os arquivos:

```
<?php

INCLUDE "conexao.php";



$sql = "SELECT * FROM consulta";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$potential = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode($potential);

?>
```

Usando este código javascript, o auto complete funciona:

```
  <script>
$(function() {
var availableTags = [

  "Felipe Arcaro",
  "Amanda Bertollini",
  "Rafael Manaus",
  "Gleidson",
  "Guilherme Sato",
  "C++",
  "Clojure",
  "COBOL",
  "ColdFusion",
  "Erlang",
  "Fortran",
  "Groovy",
  "Haskell",
  "Java",
  "JavaScript",
  "Lisp",
  "Perl",
  "PHP",
  "Python",
  "Ruby",
  "Scala",
  "Scheme"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

Mas usando esse, não:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var availableTags = <?php print(json_encode($potential)); ?>;
console.log(myArray);
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Tente trocar o json_encode por

JSON.stringify(json);

var availableTags = <?php print(JSON.stringify($potential)); ?>;

Comment: Não misture as funções MYSQLi com as mysql_*

Comment: Eduardo, não funcionou. Rray, já arrumei mas parece que esse não era o problema. Devo usar algum plugin? Estava pensando em usar select2 uma vez que gostaria de criar "tags" com cada seleção.

Answer (score 1):

No caso, é preciso enviar uma requisição via ajax e para listar, você tem que definir o parâmetro que será listado, no caso eu coloquei um campo **tag**:

```
<?php

require "conexao.php";
$sql = "SELECT tag FROM consulta";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$potential = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo json_encode(array('result' => $potential));
die();
?>
```

Imagino que sua saída convertida seja algo desse tipo:

```
{"result":
    {
         "0":"PHP",
         "1":"Javascript",
         "2":"Ruby"
    }
}
```

Então para seu script funcionar, você deve receber o parâmetro através de uma requisição ao seu arquivo: **seu_ajax.php**

```
<script>
$(function() {
     ('#tags').autocomplete({
         source: function (request, response) {
             $.post("seu_ajax.php", function (data) {
                 response($.map(data.result, function (value, key) {
                     return {
                         label: value,
                         value: key
                     };
                 }));
             });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    delay: 100
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui fazer funcionar.

Código completar.php:

```
<?
include "conexao.php";

$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM consulta";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

$resJsonF = '[';
$first = true;

while($res = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)):

    if(!$first):
    $resJsonF .= ', ';

    else:
     $first = false;
    endif;
    $resJsonF .= json_encode($res['funcao']);

endwhile;

$resJson .= ']';



?>
```

Não esqueça de chamar a função completar.php no começo do código!

Código JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(function() {
var tagNome = <?php echo $resJsonN; ?>;
$( "#completaNome" ).autocomplete({
source: tagNome
});
});
```

Como crio uma condição para trazer apenas os 4 mais pertinentes no auto completar? Quero isso pois estarei trabalhando com um banco de dados de 30k linhas, e acredito que isso seja necessário. 
O autocomplete do jquery já possui essa condição pré-definida?